# Pandas filter dataframe on multiple columns wrt corresponding column values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, `df1`:

```
a b c d e f
1 1 1 x 1 5
1 1 1 x 1 6
1 1 1 y 1 5
1 1 1 y 1 7
```

and another dataframe, `df2`:

```
a b c d e f
1 1 1 x 1 5
```

Now I want to filter `df1` on columns `a, b, c, d` if it is present in respective columns of `df2`. This is what I tried:

```
mask = df1['a'].isin(df2['a']) & df1['b'].isin(df2['b']) & df1['c'].isin(df2['c']) & df1['d'].isin(df2['d'])
df_new = df1[mask]
```

so `df_new` finally contains:

```
a b c d e f
1 1 1 x 1 5
1 1 1 x 1 6
```

I am looking for a better approach as there are a lot of columns to compare and a lot of rows, both in `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: http://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/intersection-two-dataframe-pandas-python-2/ and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge dataframes like done here in [Pandas Merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html). You also need to read on `dataframe joins` which is a common topic in learning databases.Here I have not done any tweaking with indices i.e, whether to keep left ones or right ones but you can check the docs for better information on here [Merge Docs Pydata](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge)

```
import pandas as pd

columns = "a b c d e f".split()
data = '''1 1 1 x 1 5
1 1 1 x 1 6
1 1 1 y 1 5
1 1 1 y 1 7'''.split("\n")

data = list(map(lambda x:x.split(), data ))
```

---

```
left = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns, data=data)



    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   1   1   1   x   1   5
1   1   1   1   x   1   6
2   1   1   1   y   1   5
3   1   1   1   y   1   7
```

---

```
right = pd.DataFrame(data = ["1 1 1 x 1 5".split()], columns=columns)


    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   1   1   1   x   1   5
```

---

```
pd.merge(left, right, how="right", on=["a", "b", "c", "d"])

    a   b   c   d   e_x f_x e_y f_y
0   1   1   1   x   1   5   1   5
1   1   1   1   x   1   6   1   5
```

---

```
pd.merge(left, right, how="right", on=["a", "b", "c", "d"], suffixes=["", "_"] ).drop(["e_", "f_"], axis=1)


    a   b   c   d   e   f
0   1   1   1   x   1   5
1   1   1   1   x   1   6
```

---

Comment: Those screenshots don't make the answer clearer. You can use to_clipboard to get a decent text representation